# Name Based Virtual Hosting url not found

Tags: apache, ubuntu, web-hosting

I am trying to set up a website with name based virtual hosting. Now when I visit the website, lukej.us, I get a url not found error. Here is the conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.lukej.us
  ServerAlias lukej.us *.lukej.us
  DocumentRoot /vars/www/html/lukej.html
</VirtualHost>


<Directory /vars/www/html/>
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</directory>
```

Comment: Did you restart apache to reload the changes? Also remember to edit the right php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentRoot` is supposed to be a **directory**. It is the root folder from which all files will be served. You attempted to specify a file, which then gets interpreted as a directory, since it *expects a directory*. So its trying to serve from the directory `/vars/www/html/lukej.html/` which probably doesn't exist.

You probably wanted something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.lukej.us
  ServerAlias lukej.us *.lukej.us
  DocumentRoot /vars/www/html/
  DirectoryIndex lukej.html
</VirtualHost>
```

This will serve files from the `/vars/www/html/` directory, and will show the `lukej.html` as the index file (when you access the path `/` from the web).